# Get PHP to echo cPanel username

Tags: php, cpanel

Ok, so I haven't been able to find an answer to this question anywhere, which probably means it isn't possible. I come to the community to find out once and for all if what I want is a reality.

I would like to get php to echo out the cpanel user name so that in a config.php file, I would not have to manually change the username on a new site, or if I moved servers.

Much in the way the php could echo the current year, should it be possible to have an echo on the user name.

If I had this for example:

```
Cpanel path: home/userx/public_html
```

Than

```
<php echo "cpanelusername" ?>
```

I am aware there is more than echo username, however, my demonstration is only for the purpose of describing what I want.

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+the+LiveAPI+System+-+PHP+Class

Comment: Thanks, I will be studying the document now. @Dagon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cPanel UAPI for this:

```
$cpanel = new CPANEL();

$users = $cpanel->uapi('Ftp', 'list_ftp', [
    'include_acct_types' => 'main'
]);

if ($users && isset($users[0]['type']) && $users[0]['type'] == 'main') {
    $user = $users[0]['user'];

    // The cPanel username
    var_dump($user);
}
```

By setting `include_acct_types` to `main` you will only get the main FTP account, which holds the main cPanel username. The extra checks to make sure `$users[0]['type']` is set and is the main account might be an overkill, but you never know.

Source: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/UAPI+Functions+-+Ftp%3A%3Alist_ftp